# Angular & HTML / check if element is dirty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code in my HTML page:

```
<input type="text" name="dns" class="form-control ng-valid" ng-model="conf['dns']" ng-list="">
```

When I type something in the text field, its changed to:

```
<input type="text" name="dns" class="form-control ng-valid ng-dirty" ng-model="conf['dns']" ng-list="">
```

I wish to check if the field its dirty, and do some acts if so. I have the following:

```
Controller.controller('CuController',
    function($scope, $location, $modal, Controller) {
    console.log($scope.conf['dns']) //prints the value of this field
    // Wish to check if $scope.conf['dns'] is dirty
})
```

I try to use `$scope.conf[dns].$dirty`, but it returns `undefined`.

How can I check if the field is dirty (Meaning that the value of the field was changed)?

Comment: what is a dirty element?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: A field that it's value was changed

Comment: You can use $watch to see every time a value of an Angular variable is changed.

Comment: Is this in  a form? If in a form use the formName object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$dirty is a parameter of the input of your form, try `$scope.yourForm.dns.$dirty`

Comment: It seems that it doesnt know the form structure: TypeError: Cannot read property 'dns' of undefined

Answer (score 4):

You can access form properties through the form name like so:

```
$scope.myForm.dns.$dirty; // boolean
```

Comment: It seems that it doesnt know the form structure: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'dns' of undefined`